# How change docker command in ansible docker_container depending on os type

Tags: java, linux, docker, ansible

I have some ansible playbook which runs a docker container, like this:

```
  - name: Container present 
    docker_container:
      name: myapp
      state: started
      image: myapp
      restart_policy: always
      ports:
        - "7070:7070"
      command: ["java","-Dhttp.proxyHost=1.2.3.1", "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128", '-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|10.250.*.*"',"-jar", "/opt/myapp/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"]
```

I want change command depending on OS type. example If Centos - I need this command:

```
command: ["java","-jar", "/opt/myapp/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"]
```

If Ubuntu or Debian this command:

```
    command: ["java","-Dhttp.proxyHost=1.2.3.1", "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128", '-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|10.250.*.*"',"-jar", "/opt/myapp/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"]
```

I think I must do it with set_fact, but how - I don't know. Maybe like this:

```
- set_fact:
  command: '["java","-jar", "/opt/myapp/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"]'
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

but I'm not sure that it will not result in some error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direction seems fine to me.

Could you confirm that `gather_facts` is enabled on your playbook? It should be enabled by default if not overridden specifically. Also, the indentation in `set_fact` task needs to be corrected.

Sorry, I am not able to test all the distributions but something like below should work.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        command_var:
          [
            "java",
            "-jar",
            "/opt/myapp/app.jar",
            "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"
          ]
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'

    - set_fact:
        command_var:
          [
            "java",
            "-Dhttp.proxyHost=1.2.3.1",
            "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128",
            '-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|10.250.*.*"',
            "-jar",
            "/opt/myapp/app.jar",
            "--spring.profiles.active=docker,swagger"
          ]
      when: 
        - command_var is undefined
        - ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' or ansible_distribution == 'Debian'

    - name: Container present 
      docker_container:
        name: myapp
        state: started
        image: myapp
        restart_policy: always
        ports:
          - "7070:7070"
        command: "{{ command_var }}"
      when: command_var is defined
```

Comment: or the less copy pasta: `command_var: "{{ ["java"] + ([] if ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' else ["-Dhttp.proxy..."]) + ["-jar", "/opt/..."] }}"` (with nicer formatting, of course, but as an example...)